# How can I add request header automatically using http package

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

Currently I'm sending header with every request like as follow which is very repetitive.
Is there any process so that all my request will have a request header automatically ?
Or how can I avoid code repetition for the following lines:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = sharedPreferences.getString('accessToken');
    headers: {
        'Contet-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      }
```

**My complete API Request code:**

```
Future<http.Response> getAUser(userId) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = sharedPreferences.getString('accessToken');
    
    return await http.get(
      '$baseUrl/user/$userId/',
      headers: {
        'Contet-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can centralize the headers in a separate class!

```
class BaseService {
      Map<String, String> baseHeaders;
    
      Future initBaseService() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    baseHeaders= {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${preferences.getString("TOKEN")}",
    };
  }
}
```

And then, you can inherit your class with the base class to have access to these methods.

```
 class UserService extends BaseService {
      Future<http.Response> getAUser(userId) async {
        await initBaseService();
    
        return await http
            .get(
              '$baseUrl/user/$userId/',
              headers: baseHeaders,
            )
            .timeout(Duration(seconds: 30));
      }
    }
```